# Reducing filesize for landslide susceptibility map

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, simplify, generalization, file-size

I have a large .tif file that I would like to reduce to under 15MB (currently 650MB). The file shows 3 zones of landslide susceptibility (see pic below). I am processing it so that I can upload it to Mapbox.org, which requires smaller file sizes.

So far I have tried Boundary Clean and Majority Filter.
I then converted it to a shapefile and would like to run simplify, but there's not enough memory to do so.

I am now thinking of splitting it into sections and processing in piecewise manner. I am wondering if there's any better way to go about this. Some simplification (30-60 meters of offset) is ok, but I'd like to retain general shapes and locations of information.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Does the tif file have any compression on it now?  Simple color patterns like the one in the images can be highly compressed just using lzw or similar compression methods.  In terms of reducing raster size you could look at increasing the cell size using interpolation or aggregation tools.  http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/altering-the-resolution.htm

Comment: No compression currently. I want to maintain the attribute table as it will be used to display the colors. Will this be possible after LZW compression? Is there a function in ArcMap to do this compression or will it need to be done outside of the program? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Copy Raster](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm) tool to output a new GeoTIFF with [lossless compression](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/environments/compression.htm) (LZW/Deflate/LZ77).  Compression options are found in the Raster Storage Environment setting:

This will not affect your ability to have an attribute table, though I don't know if the attribute table is automatically copied across by Copy Raster, you may need to recreate it.

[image]

Comment: Though I was able to copy the raster, the compression is not showing up when I look at raster properties and file size does not appear to be changed. Another person I spoke to suggested converting the .tiff file to .img format which will reduce the size. This does seem to work, but I need to convert the file to a GeoJson format and I have not found a way to do that conversion.